# In Qubole, creation of hive external table using S3 location

Tags: hive

I am creating an external table in hive in QUBOLE. But there is no data after the table creation.
Here is my DDL statement for creation.
use vlc;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dim_retailer_txt2(
RETAILER_TENANT_ID int,
RETAILER_NAME string,
ACTIVE tinyint)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ESCAPED BY '\'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://manthan-impala-test/vi65test-txt/dim_retailer_vlc/';

Later if i check that data, there is not data

Comment: try you Location filed in below format..
s3n://"access id":"secret key"@"bucket name"/"path_to_folder"/

Comment: I tried, but im getting error saying like this - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Invalid hostname in URI

Comment: Can i get some examples like how to specify the path

Comment: I would suggest contact Qubole support for the correct syntax.. I am using Hive on EMR.. not sure about Qubole..

Answer (score 0):

> I was using S3 browser to dump data in the S3 location.When i did this in my case , some extra file which is of 1 byte size was also getting dumped to my S3 location. So while creating an table it was not able to fetch the exact data from the S3 location.